How to merge cells in Column1
I've tried everything I can to modify my script, but I'm still getting the same result and can't merge all the data from column 1. Please see my script below and the screenshot.
// Merge cells in column 1 (PLATFORM)
var startRow = 2; // Start from the second row (after headers)

for (var i = 2; i <= selectedColumns.length + 1; i++) {
  // Check if we are at the last row or the current platform is different from the next one
  if (i === selectedColumns.length + 1 || selectedColumns[i - 1][0].trim().toLowerCase() !== selectedColumns[i - 2][0].trim().toLowerCase()) {
    var numRowsToMerge = i - startRow; // Number of rows to merge
    if (numRowsToMerge > 1) {
      newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, numRowsToMerge, 1).merge(); // Merge the cells
    }
    startRow = i; // Move to the next group
  }
}


Here's my full script, and I put comment for you to understand my script. What can I try next?
function showInputBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your First Name and Last Name.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var userInput = input.getResponseText().trim();
    if (!userInput) {
      ui.alert("Please enter your First Name and Last Name");
      return;
    }

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var userSelectedRep = userInput.toLowerCase();

    var newData = data.filter(function (r) {
      return r[23].toLowerCase() == userSelectedRep;
    });

    if (newData.length === 0) {
      ui.alert("No data found for the entered name. Please check your input.");
      return;
    }

    var selectedMonth;
    var validMonthYear = false;

    while (!validMonthYear) {
      var monthInput = ui.prompt("Please enter the month and year (e.g., September 2024):", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      
      if (monthInput.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
        var userInputMonthYear = monthInput.getResponseText().trim();
        var dateParts = userInputMonthYear.split(' ');

        // Validate input
        if (dateParts.length === 2) {
          selectedMonth = dateParts[0].toLowerCase();
          var year = dateParts[1];

          // Check if the month is valid
          var monthIndex = new Date(Date.parse(selectedMonth + " 1, " + year)).getMonth();
          if (monthIndex >= 0 && monthIndex < 12 && !isNaN(year)) {
            validMonthYear = true; // Input is valid
          } else {
            ui.alert("Please enter a valid month and year (e.g., September 2024).");
          }
        } else {
          ui.alert("Please enter both month and year.");
        }
      } else {
        ui.alert("Month input canceled.");
        return;
      }
    }

    var filteredMonthData = newData.filter(function (r) {
      var date = new Date(r[18]);
      return date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }).toLowerCase() === selectedMonth + ' ' + year;
    });

    if (filteredMonthData.length > 0) {
      var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
      var headers = ["PLATFORM", "TOTAL TIME", "INSTITUTION", "QUANTITY/ACCESS CODE", "START DATE", "START TIME", "END DATE", "END TIME", "TYPE OF ACCESS"];

      newWs.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length)
        .setBackground("#a4c2f4")
        .setFontWeight("bold")
        .setFontSize(12)
        .setWrap(true)
        .setVerticalAlignment("middle")
        .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      newWs.setRowHeight(1, 57);

      var colWidths = [200, 100, 500, 106, 200, 114, 115, 130, 130];
      for (var c = 1; c <= headers.length; c++) {
        newWs.setColumnWidth(c, colWidths[c - 1]);
      }

      // Prepare the data for the new sheet
      var selectedColumns = filteredMonthData.map(function (r) {
        return [r[10], r[22], r[1], r[17], r[18], r[19], r[20], r[21], r[9]];
      });

      // Set values in the new sheet
      newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);

      // Set the number format for START TIME and END TIME
      newWs.getRange(2, 6, selectedColumns.length, 1).setNumberFormat("hh:mm"); // START TIME
      newWs.getRange(2, 8, selectedColumns.length, 1).setNumberFormat("hh:mm"); // END TIME

      // Merge cells in column 1 (PLATFORM)
      var startRow = 2; // Start from the second row (after headers)

      for (var i = 2; i <= selectedColumns.length + 1; i++) {
        var currentPlatform = (i === selectedColumns.length + 1) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 2][0].trim().toLowerCase(); // Adjusted index
        var previousPlatform = (i - 1 === 1) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 3][0].trim().toLowerCase(); // Adjusted index
        
        if (currentPlatform !== previousPlatform) {
          var numRowsToMerge = i - startRow; // Number of rows to merge
          if (numRowsToMerge > 1) {
            newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, numRowsToMerge, 1).merge(); // Merge the cells
          }
          startRow = i; // Move to the next group
        }
      }

      // Align all data in the new sheet
      newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, headers.length)
        .setHorizontalAlignment("left")
        .setVerticalAlignment("middle");

      // Set headers at the top
      newWs.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);

      // Define chart range
      var chartRange = newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, 2);

      // Create the chart
      var chart = newWs.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN) // Set the chart type
        .addRange(chartRange) // Add the data range
        .setPosition(2, 11, 0, 0) // Position of the chart (row, column, offsetX, offsetY)
        .setOption('title', 'Institution Access Data for ' + selectedMonth + ' ' + year)
        .setOption('titleTextStyle', {
          color: '#333333',
          fontSize: 18,
          bold: true
        })
        .setOption('vAxis.title', 'Total Time')
        .setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle', {
          italic: true,
          color: '#666666',
          fontSize: 14
        })
        .setOption('hAxis.title', 'Platform')
        .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle', {
          italic: true,
          color: '#666666',
          fontSize: 14
        })
        .setOption('legend', { position: 'top', alignment: 'center' })
        .setOption('backgroundColor', '#f9f9f9')
        .setOption('colors', ['#4CAF50', '#2196F3']) // Customize colors
        .setOption('is3D', true) // Optional: make the chart 3D
        .setOption('width', 800) // Set a wider chart
        .setOption('height', 400) // Set a taller chart
        .setOption('hAxis.slantedText', true) // Rotate x-axis labels
        .setOption('hAxis.slantedTextAngle', 45) // Angle of rotation
        .setOption('dataLabel', true) // Show data labels
        .build();

      newWs.insertChart(chart);

    } else {
      ui.alert("No matching data found for the entered month.");
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert("Operation Canceled.");
  }
}


About merge all the data from column 1, in this case, const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).merge(); can merge all cells of data range. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between merge all the data from column 1, your showing script, and your showing image. Your showing image is your sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

If you notice, PEJ cells are being left unmerged is separate from column 1. My problem is why it can't be merged and why there's still a gap.

Could you please edit your post and add the original state of data before the merge? From what I understand the PEJ should also merge with the row that has value of 0.15, OR could it be sorting everything that has PEJ value on col 1 then merge it? With my first assumption, I have tested your code and it works fine on my end, suppose that the newWs value is newWs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); and selectedColumns is newWs.getRange(1, 1, newWs.getLastRow(), newWs.getLastColumn()).getValues(); If these are not the original var values, please also include

Merge cells
I have tested the code provided above, I noticed that the first snippet is somehow different from the completed script, which I would assume that you have partly resolved some issues. Upon testing the completed script, the resulting issues are within the last merging rows, and based on how I interpret the current issue, here's how I would do it.
Revised code:
  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow = newWs.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  var currentPlatform = (i < 1) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 2][0].trim().toLowerCase();
  var previousPlatform = (i - 1 === 1) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 3][0].trim().toLowerCase(); // Adjusted index

    if (currentPlatform !== previousPlatform) {
      var numRowsToMerge = i - startRow;
      if (numRowsToMerge > 1) {
        newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, numRowsToMerge, 1).merge();
      }
      startRow = i; 
      }
    }
    if (startRow < lastRow) {
      newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 1).merge();
    }

Completed code:
function showInputBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your First Name and Last Name.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var userInput = input.getResponseText().trim();
    if (!userInput) {
      ui.alert("Please enter your First Name and Last Name");
      return;
    }

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var userSelectedRep = userInput.toLowerCase();

    var newData = data.filter(function (r) {
      return r[23].toLowerCase() == userSelectedRep;
    });

    if (newData.length === 0) {
      ui.alert("No data found for the entered name. Please check your input.");
      return;
    }

    var selectedMonth;
    var validMonthYear = false;

    while (!validMonthYear) {
      var monthInput = ui.prompt("Please enter the month and year (e.g., September 2024):", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      
      if (monthInput.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
        var userInputMonthYear = monthInput.getResponseText().trim();
        var dateParts = userInputMonthYear.split(' ');

        // Validate input
        if (dateParts.length === 2) {
          selectedMonth = dateParts[0].toLowerCase();
          var year = dateParts[1];

          // Check if the month is valid
          var monthIndex = new Date(Date.parse(selectedMonth + " 1, " + year)).getMonth();
          if (monthIndex >= 0 && monthIndex < 12 && !isNaN(year)) {
            validMonthYear = true; // Input is valid
          } else {
            ui.alert("Please enter a valid month and year (e.g., September 2024).");
          }
        } else {
          ui.alert("Please enter both month and year.");
        }
      } else {
        ui.alert("Month input canceled.");
        return;
      }
    }

    var filteredMonthData = newData.filter(function (r) {
      var date = new Date(r[18]);
      return date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }).toLowerCase() === selectedMonth + ' ' + year;
    });

    if (filteredMonthData.length > 0) {
      var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
      var headers = ["PLATFORM", "TOTAL TIME", "INSTITUTION", "QUANTITY/ACCESS CODE", "START DATE", "START TIME", "END DATE", "END TIME", "TYPE OF ACCESS"];

      newWs.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length)
        .setBackground("#a4c2f4")
        .setFontWeight("bold")
        .setFontSize(12)
        .setWrap(true)
        .setVerticalAlignment("middle")
        .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      newWs.setRowHeight(1, 57);

      var colWidths = [200, 100, 500, 106, 200, 114, 115, 130, 130];
      for (var c = 1; c <= headers.length; c++) {
        newWs.setColumnWidth(c, colWidths[c - 1]);
      }

      // Prepare the data for the new sheet
      var selectedColumns = filteredMonthData.map(function (r) {
        return [r[10], r[22], r[1], r[17], r[18], r[19], r[20], r[21], r[9]];
      });

      // Set values in the new sheet
      newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);

      // Set the number format for START TIME and END TIME
      newWs.getRange(2, 6, selectedColumns.length, 1).setNumberFormat("hh:mm"); // START TIME
      newWs.getRange(2, 8, selectedColumns.length, 1).setNumberFormat("hh:mm"); // END TIME

      var startRow = 2;
      var lastRow = newWs.getLastRow();
      
      for (var i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
      var currentPlatform = (i < 2) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 2][0].trim().toLowerCase();
      var previousPlatform = (i - 1 === 1) ? "" : selectedColumns[i - 3][0].trim().toLowerCase(); // Adjusted index

        if (currentPlatform !== previousPlatform) {
          var numRowsToMerge = i - startRow;
          if (numRowsToMerge > 1) {
            newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, numRowsToMerge, 1).merge();
          }
          startRow = i; 
          }
        }
        if (startRow < lastRow) {
          newWs.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 1).merge();
        }

      // Align all data in the new sheet
      newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, headers.length)
        .setHorizontalAlignment("left")
        .setVerticalAlignment("middle");

      // Set headers at the top
      newWs.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);

      // Define chart range
      var chartRange = newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, 2);

      // Create the chart
      var chart = newWs.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN) // Set the chart type
        .addRange(chartRange) // Add the data range
        .setPosition(2, 11, 0, 0) // Position of the chart (row, column, offsetX, offsetY)
        .setOption('title', 'Institution Access Data for ' + selectedMonth + ' ' + year)
        .setOption('titleTextStyle', {
          color: '#333333',
          fontSize: 18,
          bold: true
        })
        .setOption('vAxis.title', 'Total Time')
        .setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle', {
          italic: true,
          color: '#666666',
          fontSize: 14
        })
        .setOption('hAxis.title', 'Platform')
        .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle', {
          italic: true,
          color: '#666666',
          fontSize: 14
        })
        .setOption('legend', { position: 'top', alignment: 'center' })
        .setOption('backgroundColor', '#f9f9f9')
        .setOption('colors', ['#4CAF50', '#2196F3']) // Customize colors
        .setOption('is3D', true) // Optional: make the chart 3D
        .setOption('width', 800) // Set a wider chart
        .setOption('height', 400) // Set a taller chart
        .setOption('hAxis.slantedText', true) // Rotate x-axis labels
        .setOption('hAxis.slantedTextAngle', 45) // Angle of rotation
        .setOption('dataLabel', true) // Show data labels
        .build();

      newWs.insertChart(chart);

    } else {
      ui.alert("No matching data found for the entered month.");
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert("Operation Canceled.");
  }
}

Sample output:

Reference:
Conditional Statement
